# `SelectedIndexChanged` it is not firing

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a DropDownList and I have a `<DIV>` element, When I change the value of dropdown my `div` is not going to show up I have the following ascx code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Zgjidh Kompaninë">-- Zgjidh Kompaninë--</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Meridian Corporation">Meridian Corporation</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Meridian Express">Meridian Express</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Buka">Buka</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>       
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
 </ContentTemplate>  
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList2" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If I place this `<div id="chart_div"></div>` outside of `UpdatePanel` it works or If I just delete the `<Triggers>` tag it works but it refreshes the page both times. So Why My Div Is Not Showing UP I need hep please

I am working on a sharepoint WebPart!

Comment: Are you sure it's not showing up? Since it doesn't contain anything, it's likely that perhaps you missed it? Have you looked into the html dom tree and confirmed it's not there?

Comment: I think It is not showing even in dom I cannot find it